# difference in rails migration with and without :index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

Given the following two lines

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_posts user_id:integer:index
```

and

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_posts user_id:integer
```

What is the difference? I can't seem to grasp the concept of **:index**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference has nothing to do with the how your program will logically work.

It will affect how your database indexes and queries it's data.

Specifically, the `:index` variant will tell the database to add an index to the `user_id` column of `posts`. If the database is performing a query where it needs to find posts by user_id, then this search will be more efficient. If you never lookup posts by user_id, then you are wasting resources.

Answer (score 1):

index option create index on the field user_id, so that when you retrieve the records by user_id, the search will be significantly faster.

For indexes - what they are and how they work - 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index

One point to ponder index should be created only if you have more READ query rather more WRITE query because index are costly in terms of memory.